# Visual Studio Code SFTP plugin

Tags: gratis, ftp, sftp, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a VSCode SFTP plugin that:

- Is free, I'm willing to pay if there's only one plugin that does what I want, if the price is around $50 max, and if it's 1 time payment only.
- Supports authentication using an SSH private key and a passphrase
- Can map folders
- Works on windows 10 (All do but just to be safe I mentioned that)
- Most importantly, it should have the following feature:

if you have this mapping:

```
      "localPath": "/a/b"
      "remotePath": "/remote/a/b"
```

If you create edit a file in `"/a/b/c/d"` It should autmatically get edited on the server without any further configuration, and `c/` folder doesn't exist on the server, it should automatically create it and then upload `d` file inside it. I don't want to specify multiple paths, only the parent directory path.

PHPStorm sftp does that, [vscode-sftp](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/334#issuecomment-426481367) does not do that, I have yet to find a vscode plugin that does that

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Sonamor windows 10

Comment: Would you be willing to map the sftp as a network drive instead of using a VSCode plugin?

Comment: @Sonamor Sure, as long as when I save the file the changes get uploaded or when I press a button, it doesn't have to be a plugin, didn't know such solution is possible, let me know what you are thinking

Comment: I am not at home currently but there are software, free to use, which will map an sftp or ftp as network drive. Then you can create your file there and open it with VSCode whoever you save the changes are saved to the (s)ftp server. I will answer soon with a paid and free solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our discussion above, I believe a better solution instead of using a plugin which sometimes is cumbersome, is to use a software that will map this SFTP as a network drive on your Windows 10 machine.

There are a lot of solutions out there, some paid and some free for personal use.

**FREE for personal use**

SFTP Net Drive
https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/netdrive/

I've used it in the past, plain, simple does the job no issues. I've also used another product that NSoftware bought called Eldos SFTP Net Drive and it worked fine as well but sadly it's not available anymore.

**FREE to use even for business use**

sshfs-win + SiriKali (GUI)

https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win
https://mhogomchungu.github.io/sirikali/

It seems promising but it might be cumbersome to set up. Haven't used it

**PAID Solutions**

MountainDuck

https://mountainduck.io/comparison/

I haven't used MountainDuck personally but I've used its sister product called CyberDuck and I can only say the best words for it.

MountainDuck seems to be one of the best solutions out there which will not only allow you to mount an SFTP but WebDAV, Amazon S3, Azure Blob Storage, Google Cloud Storage, OpenStack Swift, Microsoft OneDrive, BackBlaze B2, Google Drive and Dropbox as network drives.

The price for a single license comes up to 39$ and it seems that it worth the money, especially if you will use it for business and you want a trouble-free setup + support if required.

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution is so perfect. Do you recommend any? I installed SFTP net drive, it works great, not sure if the next time I connect, it downloads everything or if there's a way to keep a copy.

Comment: I actually shows what's in the server real time. It does "download" anything locally.

Comment: I have only used Elfos sftp net drive which no longer available. If I had the extra money I would pay for a mountainduck license but I don't need such a software anymore.

Comment: Okay thank you, I wish I knew about such software 15 years ago