# Mount SFTP server?

Tags: windows, sftp

I seem to be able to add a network adress or FTP server directly in Windows explorer. It can't handle SFTP though. I know about Filezille, but there I can just access the server, not mount it. I need to mount it because I want to be able to access those files from programes on my computer, and not have to copy them around all the time.

I would want it to be open source. It does not need to mount the drive, just being able to access it with windows explorer as a folder like Google Drive is enough for me.

I'm not looking for a VSCodeplugin, as that was recommended to me. The reason is that I'm not using VSCode, so it wouldn't help me in any way.

Comment: Duplicate of this? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52491/visual-studio-code-sftp-plugin/52500#52500

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code SFTP plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52491/visual-studio-code-sftp-plugin)

Comment: @Sonamor Definitely not a duplicate of that question. OP doesn't mention anything like a plugin for an IDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows SSHFS/SFTP mounting clients](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/windows-sshfs-sftp-mounting-clients)

Comment: "I would want it to be open source" - why not just [tag:gratis] ?